# Ruby: Visibility of DSL methods?

Tags: ruby, dsl

I am trying to write a DSL for a Ruby program. It currently works like this

```
generator.format 
  title "Text"
  author "John Doe"
  body "Text"
end
generator.generate!
```

What visibility should I give the methods that are called inside of `generator.format`? Currently I am treating each of the formatting methods as `protected` but when I test them i have to wrap each call in an `instance_eval` to access them. What visibility should I declare my DSL methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I test them i have to wrap each call in an `instance_eval` to access them

You say that like there is an alternative solution.

If you want to invoke your methods without an explicit object, you must change `this` using `instance_eval`.

Now for the visibility of those methods, I suggest using the lowest visibility possible which should be `private`.

Comment: I just I didn't state it clearly enough in the question, but I was asking if there was an alternative way besides using `instance_eval` or `instance_exec` but you answer answered it. So thanks!